# Calculate Percentage of each key in Object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, percentage

So I have this data, how can I compute their respective percentages?

```
  const items = {
       google: 76,
       apple: 66,
       netflix: 53
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: `const t=Object.values(items).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/100.0,perc=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(items).map(([k,v])=>[k,v/t]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reference for you by using `reduce()`

```js
const items = {
       google: 76,
       apple: 66,
       netflix: 53
  }
 
let total = Object.values(items).reduce((acc,val) =>{
  acc += val
  return acc;
},0)

let result = Object.keys(items).reduce((acc,key) => {
  let val = items[key]
  //acc[key] = val
  acc[key] = (val/total*100).toFixed(2) +"%" + " : " + val
  return acc
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: and if I we're to put the percentage in the key names? cus im planning to put the titles on a label in a chart

Comment: @user3352042 use `acc[key] = (val/total*100).toFixed(2) +"%"` instead

Comment: no I mean within the key, Google 55%: 76, like this as im planning to show the key as one with the percentage

Comment: I mean the key itself has the percentage, meaning when I Object.key(items) it shows `Google 55%`, how do i integrate the percentage in the key string itself

Comment: @user3352042 Updated and check again

Comment: still not it, 
here is the expected:
items = {
google 38%: 76,
apple 27%: 66,
netfliex 38% :  53
}

something like this

Comment: @user3352042 this can not be done without double quote

Comment: Ok thank you, ill just try and fiddle and find a work around, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please demonstrate your own effort in the question.

But since there are already answers here, I would simply find the sum based on the entries in the object, then calculate their percentages, map these into new key-value pairs by appending the percentages to the keys, and finally using `Object .fromEntries` to put these back together into an object.  It could look like this:

```js
const addPcts = (items, entries = Object.entries (items), 
  sum = entries.reduce((a, [, b]) => a + b, 0),
  pcts = entries .map (([k, v]) => [k, v, Math .round (100 * v/sum)])
) => Object .fromEntries (pcts .map (([k, v, p]) => [`${k} ${p}%`, v]))

const items = {google: 76, apple: 66, netflix: 53}

console .log (addPcts (items))
```